# Collapse menu, have all social media icons on one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm a bootstrap n00b. So on my personal website, I have a nav bar that collapses when the screen width changes. Everything is working fine, as shown here:

[image]

However, I'd like if all of my social media icons were on one line. I have tried several things already, but I've had no luck.

Here is my html:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-     toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="./index" title="Bio">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="./Resume" title="My Resume">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/cody-reandeau-831038115" class="entypo-linkedin" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/codyreandeau" class="entypo-github" target="_blank" title="Github"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/codyreandeau" class="fontawesome-fire" target="_blank" title="Free Code Camp"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.hackerrank.com/codyareandeau" class="fontawesome-sitemap" target="_blank" title="Hacker Rank"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.codecademy.com/scriptSurfer86103" class="zocial-html5" target="_blank"  title="Codecademy"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm thinking it is something I need to do in css?

```
 .navbar-collapse {
   display:inline;
 }
```

^I've tried this, however it doesn't work; I imagine it is a little more complicated than just that. Any help at all would be great!

Comment: All your social buttons seem to be in `navbar-right`, so try `.navbar-right li { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

```
.navbar-right li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @Cody Glad that i helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `<li>` elements themselves. Have you tried something like:

```
ul.nav li {
   display: inline;
}
```

You could also use `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .nav>li{
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}